# How to add an image with PageTitleStrip in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, page-title

I am using PageTitleStrip for swiping my Fragments.
I need to use a circular image with corresponding page title.
So please help me out.

Suggestions appreciated.
Thanks Regards
Shoeb Ahmed.

Comment: AFAIK, `PagerTitleStrip` does not support what you want, so my guess is that you will need to switch to a different indicator. Perhaps one of the ViewPagerIndicator ones will handle your needs, or else you may have to write one yourself.

Comment: @CommonsWare. I am using PageTitleStrip inside ViewPagerIndicator.

Comment: ViewPagerIndicator does not have a class named `PageTitleStrip`, last I checked.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this lib from here you can modify as you want https://github.com/jittya/SwipeableTabView

Comment: its a combination view pager and tab its easily customizable .you can download source files and keep in your project and customize as you want